# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0] on project ':app'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have the error I put in the title and put below. The error occurs when building my flutter project. I created my project with the Android [Max 2D Game](https://max2dgame.com/) app on my Samsung Galaxy A10. I build by [codemagic](https://codemagic.io/).

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I invite you to explore my project on [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/#https://github.com/alexandroGonSan/firstplay) or fork on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexandroGonSan/firstplay) and submit a pull request fixing this error. Before submitting the pull request, see if [CodeMagic](https://codemagic.io/) builds correctly.

My `android/build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My `android/app/build.gradle` is:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.company.firstplay"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (System.getenv()["CI"]) {
                storeFile file(System.getenv()["FCI_KEYSTORE_PATH"])
                storePassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"]
                keyAlias System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_ALIAS"]
                keyPassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_PASSWORD"]
            } else {
                
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            if (System.getenv()["CI"]) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            } else {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0"
```

Comment: That won't be defined at the top level of the file; it should be in a closure passed to `dependencies`. Check out https://android-doc.github.io/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: this solved for me